# Can I migrate content to non drupal sites

Tags: migrations

I've been reading up on Drupal migration module recently and it seems like very powerful tool. That's why I was wondering is it possible to make migrations like `Wordpress -> Joomla` with Drupal only as intermediary between those two.

I tried to find some answers to this question but so far I've found only X -> drupal migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but none of the pre-created classes are there for you such as `MigrateDestinationNode` where all the fields would be known by the Migrate system. Migrate is a general migration tool to move X to Y; but if you're new to it you may find trying to leverage it to the fullest capabilities as a migration tool somewhat difficult.

But, what I like Migrate is that it encapsulates the concept of a migration lifecycle:

1. get me the data from the source X

   - should I sanitize it before I grab it from source X ?
2. prepare to use the data

   - should i translate the data before making use of it in destination Y?
3. use the data in destination Y
4. do something with the data after using it (like create a cross reference)

Optionally, if the above steps are a migration of 1 element of data; you may configure pre and post migration tasks per migration as well.

Comment: Well, yes. I kind of like Migrate as migration framework. Something to crunch data. So is it possible to move data from one WP database to Joomla database with Migrate without storing data in Drupal first? I have very poverful server but shitty computer. It would be quite useful to have my own little migration setup and a personal website at the same time.

Comment: sure, migrate only stores a `Map` of source <-> destination keys per migration. This is so you can reference the end result ID of a previous migration -- without needing to run that step again. This is also so you can migration small segments of your data, or resume a migration. Migrate doesn't store anything really except primary keys when it needs to. If no updates to your data is ever needed you dont even need to store the Map datastructure (if it's a 1 time migration).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to try to go directly from one system into another. Placing Drupal in the middle is likely to add complexity to your migration strategy. But hey, if you find that it solves some issues that your migrations face, then I see no reason why it can't be done.